# Catalina an MAMP Database Conenction Error

Tags: database, errors, mac

Ive updated my MACOS to Catalina and MAMP Pro 5.5.1 to find none of my existing site work. All I get is 'Error establishing a database connection'. Ive moved over my httdocs and db folders. Everything is there. They just are communicating with each other. Any ideas on a fix?

Comment: Please note that this is probably a MAMP / MacOS related question and not a Wordpress related question.